# Can't write partition Table

Tags: linux, hibernate, ssd, mbr

I own an Asus UX31A Prime - 8GB Ram and SSD 256GB - SanDisk. It started about two weeks ago after hibernation (Windows).
The problem is that is stocks on boot/resume. I search around it by trying to instal Windows and Linux. I've got I/O Error on partitioning on Linux and on Wind installer i get black screen and white cursor (i found on the web is an SSD/HDD error)

I tried to delete the partitions on Linux Live CD/USB with no luck - I/O Error.

Now, what i think it is, is the partition table that can't be edited for some reason. I will post below some Commands Output from Fedora Linux Terminal.

Get Partitions Table

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

OUTPUT:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 238.5 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x90e5b865

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848 246163455 245956608 117.3G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       246163456 500115455 253952000 121.1G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Get Partition Table as ASCII Saved as TXT:

`sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda > PT.txt`

OUTPUT

```
Completed
```

Upload the same table - NO EDIT to SSD:

```
sudo sfdisk --no-reread -f /dev/sda -O PT.save < PT.txt
```

OUTPUT - WITH ERROR:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 31130 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
Old situation:
Units: cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      0+     12-     13-    102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         12+  15322-  15311- 122978304    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3      15322+  31130-  15808- 126976000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
New situation:
Units: sectors of 512 bytes, counting from 0

   Device Boot    Start       End   #sectors  Id  System
/dev/sda1   *      2048    206847     204800   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        206848 246163455  245956608   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3     246163456 500115455  253952000   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4             0         -          0   0  Empty
sfdisk: Warning: partition 1 does not end at a cylinder boundary
sfdisk: Warning: partition 2 does not start at a cylinder boundary
sfdisk: Warning: partition 2 does not end at a cylinder boundary
sfdisk: Warning: partition 3 does not start at a cylinder boundary
sfdisk: Warning: partition 3 does not end at a cylinder boundary
sfdisk: Failed writing the partition on /dev/sda: Input/output error
Re-reading the partition table ...
sfdisk: Error closing /dev/sda: Input/output error
sfdisk: If you created or changed a DOS partition, /dev/foo7, say, then use dd(1)
to zero the first 512 bytes:  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/foo7 bs=512 count=1
(See fdisk(8).)
```

Can you help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it could be read-only, can we see SMART report (use CrystalDiskInfo or similar).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to wipe the drive completely and then install the OSs.  But install Windows before you install Linux.

Comment: How to wipe it? Tried from Hiren's Boot, about 9 Hours. After Reboot "Resuming Windows"

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: Just google how to wipe a hard drive

Comment: I tried using Hiren's Boot USBm no errorsm after 9 Hours after rebooting the Old Windows was stil there. I ordered from Ebay, Asus Connector to SATA USB. Is it possbile to be fixet from USB if using motherboard socket won't work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From that fedora install USB/DVD run

```
dd bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX
```

where `X` is whatever letter that drive shows up (presumably `/dev/sdb`)

Comment: Already  tried. After reboot, old OS still there

Comment: well, can you write to any sector at all?

Answer (score 0):

First try to read the whole disk. If there is an error your disk is broken:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=4M status=progress
```

Then wipe the whole disk. Error (other than "no more space" means disk is broken):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=4M status=progress conv=fsync
sync
```